# I have an error at automapper when mapping an expression

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I am having the following code which runs flawlessly, as long as I do not uncomment the commented line:

```
var viewModel = new ArticlesListViewModel
            {
                Articles = await _context.Articles.Select(article =>

                    _mapper.Map<ArticleLookupModel>(article)

                )
               // .Where(x => x.Title.ToLower().Contains(request.PagingModel.QueryFilter.ToLower()))
               .Skip((request.PagingModel.PageNumber - 1) * request.PagingModel.PageSize).Take(request.PagingModel.PageSize)
               .ToListAsync(cancellationToken)
            };
```

If I am uncomment, at mapping I am getting the following exception:

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Article>
    .Where(a => ___mapper_0.Map<ArticleLookupModel>(a).Title.ToLower().Contains(__ToLower_1))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().
```

My automapper Profile is the following, where Title property is nothing else but an ordinary string:

```
public class ArticleProfile : Profile
    {
        public ArticleProfile() 
        {
            CreateMap<Article, ArticleLookupModel>()
                .ForMember(title=>title.Title, conf=>conf.MapFrom(dto=>dto.Title));
        }
    }
```

I know that I have to declare somewhere, something like this (I am not sure if it's correct or complete)

```
  Expression<Func<Article, bool>> dtoExpression = dto => dto.Title.ToLower().Contains(request.PagingModel.QueryFilter.ToLower());
        var expression = _mapper.Map<Expression<Func<ArticleLookupModel, bool>>>(dtoExpression);
```

I want to make a string comparison, ignoring the case (that's why I am calling the ToLower() method). However I don't know what should I do with these two lines of code, how to add it to the configuration.

I want to perform the mapping while creating the list asynchronously, for performance reasons. I do not want to create a list of mapped models and then to iterate it again and take what respects my condition.

Comment: as errors suggests, try `AsEnumerable` before the `where`

Comment: Try `ProjectTo` instead. See http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html.

Comment: Thanks for answering guys! Acctuallly the solution that I found was to include the respositotypatter that I had to do it anyway .. something like this:

Comment: var viewModel = new ArticlesListViewModel
            {
                Articles = await
                _repoWrapper.Article.FindByCondition(dto => dto.Title.ToLower().Contains(request.PagingModel.QueryFilter.ToLower()))           
                .Select(article =>
                    _mapper.Map<ArticleLookupModel>(article)
                )
               .Skip((request.PagingModel.PageNumber - 1) * request.PagingModel.PageSize).Take(request.PagingModel.PageSize)
               .ToListAsync(cancellationToken)
            };